# User Secrets not loading with WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

Tags: webapi, .net-7.0, user-secret

My understanding from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows#register-the-user-secrets-configuration-source) is the userSecret configuration is supposed to be automatically created by the  WebApplication.CreateBuilder() while in the development environment. This is not true for my current WebAPI .net7 application. I have run the init command and populated the secrets file. Any ideas on why the userSecrets would be missing from the configuration sources?

Comment: If you run `dotnet user-secrets list` in the project folder of the asp.net app what did you get? Can you find your settings. Could you include a sample of the secrets.json and of the code that access configuration?

Comment: The UserSecrets configuration source is not being added. I have to manually add the AddUserSecrets method myself which conflicts with the Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: `dotnet user-secrets init` will create new secrets.json for the project and update `UserSecretsId` in .csproj file. If you did not initialize usec-secrets store or did not specify `UserSecretsId` then ASP.NET Core will not load the secret file.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The initialized `WebApplicationBuilder` (`builder`) provides default configuration and calls `AddUserSecrets` when the `EnvironmentName` is **Development**.

Ensure that your environment is set to `Development`. This is usually done via the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable for web apps.